# Существуют ли книги и учебники программирование Java под Android?

Tags: java, android

Java используется много где и так же для программирования мобильных приложений под Android. Существуют ли книги и учебники программирование Java под Android?

Answer (score 4):

Да, конечно, существуют.

Из наиболее качественных и актуальных, на мой взгляд:

1. [«Android. Программирование для профессионалов», Брайн Харди, Билл Филлипс](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/135513511/), 2-е издание (это важно!);
2. [«Android для разработчиков», Пол Дейтел, Харви Дейтел](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/136331151/)

Есть еще несколько книжек от Рето Майера и других уважаемых людей, но их переведенные варианты уже несколько устарели.

На английском языке книг, естественно, больше.

И еще, хочу сразу Вас предупредить: если Вы не знаете Java и хотите программировать под Android, не начинайте обучение сразу с Android SDK, начните с изучения самого Java. Для программирования под Android как минимум необходимо знать Java Core на хорошем уровне (плюс базовые вещи, вроде структур данных и классических алгоритмов).

По Java книг больше. Из классики: Шилдт, Эккель, Хорстманн, Блох и много других.

Answer (score 0):

На английском языке:

```
Sams Teach Yourself Android™ Application Development in 24 Hours
```

Для этой книги Вы построите полную аппликациу.